# ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync frequently fails with 'WaitingForConnection'

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, gprs

We have a solution running on WM 6.5 that connects to our servers but one of our customers has frequent problems where our software loses its gprs connection and is unable to get a new one until the phone is rebooted.

We know that the phone is in a gprs area as we are able to remote desktop into the phone and browse using internet explorer. Our logs show that although we have specified a 2 minute time out, ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync returns with a waitingForConnection status. Does anybody have any ideas what could be going wrong? eg Is it possible that some 3rd party software is stealing our connection?

Many Thanks.

```
private void Connect()
    {
        if (_connectionHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            EventLog.AddLogEntry(LogSeverity.Trace, "connmgr - current handle was:" + _connectionHandle);
            CloseConnection();
        }

        const int connectionTimeout = 120000;

        const int CONNMGR_PARAM_GUIDDESTNET = 1;
        const int CONNMGR_PRIORITY_USERINTERACTIVE = 0x8000;
        const int CONNMGR_FLAG_SUSPEND_AWARE = 0x10; // suspended connections supported
        const int CONNMGR_FLAG_NO_ERROR_MSGS = 0x40; // don't show any error messages for failed connections
        const int CONNMGR_proxies = 0x3;
        const string testUrl = "http://www.bbc.co.uk";

        ConnectionInfo info = new ConnectionInfo();
        info.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        info.bExclusive = 0;
        info.dwFlags = CONNMGR_proxies | CONNMGR_FLAG_NO_ERROR_MSGS | CONNMGR_FLAG_SUSPEND_AWARE;
        info.dwPriority = CONNMGR_PRIORITY_USERINTERACTIVE;

        Guid networkGuid = Guid.Empty;
        int hResult = MobileNativeMethods.ConnMgrMapURL(testUrl, ref networkGuid, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (hResult != 0)
        {
            EventLog.AddLogEntry(LogSeverity.Trace, "<<Dllimport - ConnMgrMapURL (error) " + hResult.ToString());
            throw new ConnectionUnavailableException("Unable to open connection");
        }

        info.guidDestNet = networkGuid;
        info.dwParams = CONNMGR_PARAM_GUIDDESTNET;
        uint status = 0;
        hResult = MobileNativeMethods.ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync(ref info, out _connectionHandle, (uint)connectionTimeout, out status);
        if (hResult != 0)
        {
            EventLog.AddLogEntry(LogSeverity.Trace, "<<Dllimport - ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync (error) " + networkGuid.ToString());
            throw new ConnectionUnavailableException("Unable to open connection: " + (ConnectionStatus) status);
        }
        EventLog.AddLogEntry(LogSeverity.Trace, "<<Dllimport - ConnMgrMapURL Connection OK");
    }
```

Comment: What is ConnMgrProxy = 0x03, this const value is not listed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx. As connections established via ConnMgr are normally shared, did you think about using bExclusive? Another question is, what happens if the user tries a manual connect on the device using the provided connection, that means: what happens if the user tries to open the web site in InternetExplorerMobile? - If the phone is used in voice mode, the ConnMgr can normally not establish a data connection.

Comment: Hi josef, in my hacking around to try to fix things I added that, its an amalgamation of enable HTTP and WAP proxies. I get the same problem with and without it. I haven't tried exclusive as our software maintains a long term connection so it would kill other applications. It has occurred to me that some other app could have the exclusive flag set. is there any way to check for that? The User has reported that he is able to use internet explorer while our comms are down

Comment: So, you mean another app has opened an exclusive connection? If so, why can the user browse the internet using the existing connection? Possibly you can try a http request before starting your own connmgr connection. If the http request fails (which should not happen, as this should fire up an internet connection), you may start a connmgr connect request. Possibly you have an error in your connection setup. Maybe you try the MSDN connmgr C# example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb840031.aspx or OpenNetCF. I will look for a ConnMgr logger.

Comment: I have done a ConnMgr logging tool (C#, OpenNetCF). You can download the source and binary of www.hjgode.de/temp/ConnectionManagerLog.zip. It lists the known connections and there state all 30 seconds to a log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found out that setting the AlwaysOn setting in the registry to false fixed the issue. I suspect that there is a deeper problem with Honeywell devices and this setting as Motorola devices seemed to work fine regardless of its value.